# What Tools Exist for Comparing Two Files?

Tags: web-development, website-design

what tools do you guys use to compare two scripts, basically i modded an template and need to compare this template with the new release of this template. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try any "diff" and/or "merge" tool out there that you're most comfortable with.

**On Windows** you can try [Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) or [BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) or [IDM UltraCompare](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultracompare.html) or [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/index.html) if your on Windows.

**On linux** and friends you can use the [command diff](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_diff.htm) or [graphical ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112932/graphical-diff-programs-for-linux).

**On Mac OS X** you can try [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/) or [UltraCompare](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultracompare-mac-linux.html) or [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge_mac/index.html) or even [XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) which comes with FileMerge.

You also can use [many](http://www.mergely.com/) [various](http://www.diffchecker.com/) [online](http://www.text-compare.com/) [diff](http://www.diffnow.com/) and [merge](http://www.quickdiff.com/) [tools](http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/diff/diff.html).

Most version control GUI software, like [tortoisegit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) and [tortoisesvn](http://tortoisesvn.net) also come with a diff/merge tool.

Comment: Most decent code editors have a diff tool, e.g. Notepad++ or Sublime Text 2.